# multiple port forwarding gives bind: Address already in use

Tags: networking, 16.04, ssh

I would like to use multiple port forwarding to run a backend of an application that uses two databases running on a remote server. I am quite new to this. I am running this command:

```
ssh -L 5432:IP_remote:5432 -L 3333:IP_remote:3306 user@IP_remote
```

My understanding is that my localhost should see the db data at port 5432 and 3333. Is that right? When I launch this command I connect to the server but the first line says:

```
bind: Address already in use
```

Does this refer to my localhost or the remote server? runnig on my localhost BEFORE connecting with the server:

```
netstat -tulpn

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1526/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1125/postgres
```

5432 is being used by postgres so I tried to change port 5432 to 5433 in the ssh command but I still get the same error.

Runnig the previous command, i.e.  netstat -tulpn on my localhost AFTER the connection has been established gives:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3333          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6247/ssh        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      6247/ssh        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3333                :::*                    LISTEN      6247/ssh
```

Does this indicate that is working fine? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The port 3333 is used in your local host so the error comes from your side. Some other process is already using this port on your computer.